# tomcat isn't visible when trying to run jsp file

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

[image]

when trying to run the jsp file, various versions of tomcat should be placed on the list but none of them are visible.

Will appreciate if you give some hints regarding the problem
thanks!

Comment: Did you install *Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers* or did you add web tools later on?

Comment: Guess I did the former one

Comment: It looks like the dialog is merely vertically squashed, like there isn't enough room to lay out all of its controls.

Comment: Apparently they aren't there in the first place that's why it looks so